# include parent fields in Attachment query

Tags: apex, soql

This query works fine except I was not able to show custom field called custom_Date__c in SELECT.

```
SELECT Id,ContentType,BodyLength, ParentId, Parent.Name 
FROM Attachment 
WHERE Parent.Type ='Incident__c ' 
     AND ParentId in ( SELECT Id FROM Incident__c WHERE  custom_Date__c < 2018-12-31)
```

This is what I want it to happen.

```
SELECT Id,ContentType,BodyLength, ParentId, Parent.Name, *Parent.custom_Date__c*  
    FROM Attachment 
    WHERE Parent.Type ='Incident__c' 
         AND ParentId in ( SELECT Id FROM Incident__c WHERE  custom_Date__c < 2018-12-31)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the [TYPEOF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm) operator:

```
SELECT Id,ContentType,BodyLength, ParentId, Parent.Name, 
  TYPEOF Parent WHEN ObjectName__c THEN Custom_Date__c END 
    FROM Attachment 
    WHERE Parent.Type ='Incident__c' 
         AND ParentId in ( SELECT Id FROM Incident__c WHERE  custom_Date__c < 2018-12-31)
```

Comment: Thank you it worked!